# Reference for rigorous derivation of bigram model

Tags: probability, natural-language

The unigram model for bodies of text makes the assumption that in a given corpus the value of the $n$th word is independent of the $n-1$th word. Then, for a fixed dictionary $D$ and a corpus of text $T$, the unigram model assigns to each $d\in D$ the probability $\mathbb{P}(d)=\frac{\textrm{count}(d)}{|D|}$. This is justified by the fact that the probability of $T$ occurring is (by our independence assumption) the product of the probabilities of each word in $T$, and the aforementioned probability distribution is the one maximizing the likelihood of $T$. (So this is an MLE model). This can be proved using some simple calculus - http://pages.uoregon.edu/aarong/teaching/G4075_Outline/node13.html.

I'm trying to understand the bigram (and more generally $n$-gram model) in the same way. There the underlying assumption is that the value of the $k$th word depends only on the value of the $k-1$th word (and is thus independent of the $k-2$th word). Then, according to wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_model#n-gram_models) and a host of other sources, $\mathbb{P}(b|a)=\textrm{count}(ab) / \textrm{count}(a)$.

Can anyone point to a derivation of this formula, preferably appealing to MLE and calculus? The thing blocking me from seeing this as straightforward is that unlike unigrams, bigrams are not independent of each other. For example, if I tell you ab has a nonzero chance of occurring, then so does some bigram starting with a b.

Comment: did you find any solution to it?